# What to use for localhost datasource in C# connection string

Tags: c#, mysql

I am currently trying to connect to a database on my localhost with C#, but I don't know what to use for `datasource`.

I have already tried 'localhost', 127.0.0.1 and "(local)" .  I honestly don't know what to do. Does anybody know what to do?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Database_connection
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString;
            SqlConnection cnn;

            string dataSource = "127.0.0.1";

            connetionString = "Data Source=" + dataSource + ";Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=root;Password=root";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            cnn.Open();

            MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
>   The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could
>   not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: "localhost" should work just fine.  How are you connecting to the database in the editor?  If you're using SSMS it will show the connection string used.

Comment: The problem is that you are using the Sql Server libraries to connect to a MySql server. This will never work. You need the appropriate connector for MySql

Comment: @steve would changing SqlConnection to MySqlConnection work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have MySql installed on your local machine then you need the MySql libraries for NET (AKA Net Connector) and you can download them from here:

[MySQL Community Downloads](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

After installing the libraries you need to add a reference into your project

[Manage references in a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019)

at this point you instruct your code that you want to use the classes in the namespace provided by the libraries adding

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

at the top of your file source.

Finally you change the classes to use the correct one:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connetionString;
    connetionString = $"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=root;Password=root";
    using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connetionString))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the problem was that i used SQL for a MySql database. Changing SqlConnection to MySqlConnection works